# How to create ehotkeys in windows

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I would like to know how to create hotkeys in Windows without pasting the shortcut onto my desktop. Current if I create a shortcut it looks only in the desktop. But I dont want to put my icon on the desktop. I know of third party software like WinKey but I want to know if this is possible without using any external software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you create a folder on the root of your drive and put all your shortcuts in there, that way you dont have an icon on the desktop but you can still use the hotkey feature.

If you dont want to create shortcuts of at all, you will need third party software.

Comment: Where in the root? Is it in C drive. IF so I created C:/shortcuts and put it there but it did not work

Comment: @Sab: Where you desktop folder is depends on what version of Windows you're using. Try searching your C: drive for a folder named "desktop". One of them will be yours -- the one which is a subfolder of your username.

Comment: @Sab i just did it on Windows 7 and it works fine, create C:\Shortcuts then paste all your shortcuts in there and right click on then and select properties, and set the hotkeys.

Comment: Strange. I did precisely the same thing and it doesnt work. Do you have the same shortcut on your Desktop by any chance?

Comment: nope, i actually cut and pasted the shortcut from my desktop, you can try that.

Comment: OKay, will do so.